# Prolog number generation between Number 1 and Number 2

Tags: prolog

I need to write a prolog program that will give the numbers between N1 and N2 (both are included). I have written this program but it is giving a single element at the output. Thanks for your help.

```
generate_num(X) :- in_between(N1, N2, X).

in_between(I,I,I).
in_between(I,J,I) :- I =< J.
in_between(I,J,K) :- I < J, I1 is I+1, in_between(I1,J,K).
```

Comment: `N1` and `N2` are variables? Exactly how do you call this?

Comment: You basically want to program [`between/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)

Comment: `| ?- in_between(1,5,K).
K = 1 ? ;
K = 2 ? ;
K = 3 ? ;
K = 4 ? ;
K = 5 ? ;
K = 5 ? ;
no`
So, it is incorrect (the upper limit appear twice among the solutions), but it does not give "a single element". You need to clarify your question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes N1 and N2 are variables which will be taken from user for an exmple if I give N1 as 10 and N2 as 15 then the output will be = [10,11,12,13,14,15].

Comment: @PerMildner : For an example here I want to give my input N1 as 10 and N2 as 15 then the output will be = [10,11,12,13,14,15].

Comment: @Dev: but where do you take these as input? Right now you run this with ungrounded variables.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : Okay look I am very new to prolog so unable to explain may be, so trying the most naive approach. If I type ?-some_Function_name(10,13,L). Then L will show L=[10,11,12,13] as output.

Comment: @dev So, your `in_between` needs to produce a list, not a single number. You need to consider what the different cases are when producing a list. The program will be similar to what you already have (but, as I mentioned, the program currently produce duplicates of some numbers, which is a separate bug). As already hinted at, there are similar code in library/between.pl that you can look at if you get completely stuck.

Comment: Here is an implementation: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/f660a9314d42dbb477acd90b5b7ad935fb711e8d/library/lists.pl#L587-L605